# how to assign Croppie returned result to IMG?

Tags: jquery

I've using Croppie jQuery plugin for crop a image And returns a the cropped image encoded in base64.

My Code as below:

```
$uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
    type: 'canvas',
    size: 'viewport'
}).then(function (resp) {
    var blobBin = atob(resp.split(',')[1]);
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < blobBin.length; i++) {
        array.push(blobBin.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    var file = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/png'});
    //How to assign this to image
});
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign directly to img because returns a the cropped image encoded in base64

http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

```
$uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
    type: 'canvas',
    size: 'viewport'
}).then(function (resp) {
    $('#img_elem_id').attr('src', resp);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set type as **base64** then do this

```
croppie.result({
    type: 'base64'
})
.then(function (resp) {
    image.src = resp;
});
```

If you set type as **blob** then do this

```
croppie.result({
    type: 'blob'
})
.then(function (blob) {
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob, { oneTimeOnly: true });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new image and reference the image source to the blob, then append the image to your desired element

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
document.body.appendChild(image);
```